# How to Assign screen results from a function to variables in R

Tags: r

I'm new in R. I am using a Library called "CircStat". Functions in that library print the results on the screen, for example

```
rao.spacing(angles)
```

gives

```
Rao's Spacing Test of Uniformity 

Test Statistic = 155.9671 

0.001 < P-value < 0.01
```

where "rao.spacing is the function, and "angles" is a list of several angles in rad.

I need to pass the output, specifically, "155.9671" to a variable to use it in other parts of my code, How can I do that?

I prefer to do NOT write to a file and read from that, because I need to use the function for more that 50,000. And printing would be very time consuming.

Thanks,
Moe

Comment: Where can one install said package? It doesn't seem to be on CRAN. Can you not use the `<-` operator to assign the results of `rao.spacing()` to an object?

Comment: My bad, it is "CircStats" and is on CRAN.

Comment: No, I tried, all kind of operating, what I get is NULL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the author of CircStats didn't think functions needed to return a value--`rao.spacing()` is designed to return NULL (note in the help for `rao.spacing()`, the VALUE section is simpley "NULL").

However, if you examine the function itself (hit F2 in Rstudio, or type in the function without any parenthesis or arguments), it's pretty simple to hack in a return value by creating your own version:

```
rao2  <- function (x, alpha = 0, rad = TRUE) 
{
  rao.table <- NULL
  data(rao.table, package = "CircStats", envir = sys.frame(which = sys.nframe()))
  if (rad == TRUE) 
    x <- deg(x)
  x <- sort(x%%360)
  n <- length(x)
  spacings <- c(diff(x), x[1] - x[n] + 360)
  U <- 1/2 * sum(abs(spacings - 360/n))
  if (n < 4) 
    stop("Sample size too small")
  if (n <= 30) 
    table.row <- n - 3
  else if (n <= 32) 
    table.row <- 27
  else if (n <= 37) 
    table.row <- 28
  else if (n <= 42) 
    table.row <- 29
  else if (n <= 47) 
    table.row <- 30
  else if (n <= 62) 
    table.row <- 31
  else if (n <= 87) 
    table.row <- 32
  else if (n <= 125) 
    table.row <- 33
  else if (n <= 175) 
    table.row <- 34
  else if (n <= 250) 
    table.row <- 35
  else if (n <= 350) 
    table.row <- 36
  else if (n <= 450) 
    table.row <- 37
  else if (n <= 550) 
    table.row <- 38
  else if (n <= 650) 
    table.row <- 39
  else if (n <= 750) 
    table.row <- 40
  else if (n <= 850) 
    table.row <- 41
  else if (n <= 950) 
    table.row <- 42
  else table.row <- 43
  if (alpha == 0) {
    cat("\n")
    cat("       Rao's Spacing Test of Uniformity", "\n", 
        "\n")
    cat("Test Statistic =", round(U, 5), "\n")
    if (U > rao.table[table.row, 1]) 
      cat("P-value < 0.001", "\n", "\n")
    else if (U > rao.table[table.row, 2]) 
      cat("0.001 < P-value < 0.01", "\n", "\n")
    else if (U > rao.table[table.row, 3]) 
      cat("0.01 < P-value < 0.05", "\n", "\n")
    else if (U > rao.table[table.row, 4]) 
      cat("0.05 < P-value < 0.10", "\n", "\n")
    else cat("P-value > 0.10", "\n", "\n")
  }
  else {
    cat("\n")
    cat("       Rao's Spacing Test of Uniformity", "\n", 
        "\n")
    cat("Test Statistic =", round(U, 5), "\n")
    if (sum(alpha == c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1)) == 0) 
      stop("Invalid significance level")
    table.col <- (1:4)[alpha == c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1)]
    critical <- rao.table[table.row, table.col]
    cat("Level", alpha, "critical value =", critical, "\n")
    if (U > critical) 
      cat("Reject null hypothesis of uniformity", "\n", 
          "\n")
    else cat("Do not reject null hypothesis of uniformity", 
             "\n", "\n")
  }


  return(U)
}

myvalue  <- rao2(angles)
```

Note the `return(U)` at the end, which kicks out the value you're looking for (though, without performing the sort of significance testing that the function is designed to do--you'll need to perform those sort of sanity checks yourself).

Comment: That helped a lot! I appreciate!